# MySQL join of 3 tables - get aggregate value from 2 child tables

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I need to create a summary from 3 different tables, 1 parent table, 2 child tables.

How can I get the number of records from two child tables, based on the user id (pk in each of the 3 tables).

Parent table (`user`) pk is userId
Child tables 1 and 2 have composite pks of userId and webId.

I know this isn't the proper SQL syntax, but it illustrates what I'm after.

```
select u.userId, count(table1.webId), count(table2.webId)
from `user` u 
left join `table1` t1 on u.userId = t1.userId
left join `table2` t2 on u.userId = t2.userId
group by u.userId
```

Comment: Actually, that looks like it will work just fine. Did you try it?

Comment: What is wrong with the output from your current attempt?

Comment: The values for the counts are too high and always equal:
(userid)42 (count from table 1)1391 (count from table 2)1391

Comment: Original author, can you change the second left join to refer to table2?

Comment: Because there is no one-to-one join between table1 and table2 you end up with the Cartesian product of the two userId based subsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to add `DISTINCT` -

```
SELECT u.userId, COUNT(DISTINCT table1.webId), COUNT(DISTINCT table2.webId)
FROM `user` u 
LEFT JOIN `table1` t1
    ON u.userId = t1.userId
LEFT JOIN `table2` t2
    ON u.userId = t2.userId
GROUP BY u.userId
```

Comment: well I'll be damned. The distinct fixed it... (will accept this as the answer as soon as I'm allowed.)

Comment: You should be allowed to straight away. Just click the tick next to the answer :)

Comment: @nnicols: I get a message that I have to wait x minutes.

Comment: @acedanger - sorry, I forgot about that.